# RISC-V using stack in recursive call

Tags: assembly, stack, riscv

Can someone explain how the a0 pointer doesn't get reverted back to the original value?
The code below takes the string created using the DC instruction and reverses it. Trecrev is called recursively, and uses the stack to store values. I can understand why ra is saved. If we dont save it, we would lose the return address back to main. But why do we need to save a0 and a1. Furthermore, if we load a0 back into a0, how come we aren't reverting the string back to normal?

```
STR:    DC  "Hadoukan\0"

main:
    addi    a0, x0, STR
    jal ra, strlen
    addi    a1, a0, -1
    addi    a0, x0, STR
    jal ra, trecrev
    addi    x5, x0, STR
    ecall   x0, x5, 4
    ebreak  x0,x0, 0

trecrev:
    bge x0, a1, trecrevbase
    addi    sp, sp, -24
    sd  ra, 0(sp)
    sd  a0, 8(sp)
    sd  a1, 16(sp)
    add a1, a1, a0
    jal ra, excharr
    ld  ra, 0(sp)
    ld  a0, 8(sp)
    ld  a1, 16(sp)
    addi    sp, sp, 24
    addi    a0, a0, 1
    addi    a1, a1, -2
    jal x0, trecrev

trecrevbase:
    jalr    x0, 0(ra)


;;; EXCHARR
;;; expects two arguments (pointers to characters) and
;;; exchanges the two characters
excharr:
    lb  t0, 0(a0)
    lb  t1, 0(a1)
    sb  t1, 0(a0)
    sb  t0, 0(a1)
    jalr    x0, 0(ra)


;;; STRLEN
;;; expacts one argument pointer to char and returns the length of the
;;; string.
;;; t0  -> counter
;;; t1  -> temp to read the char in.
strlen:
    addi    t0, x0, 0
strlenloop:
    lb  t1, 0(a0)
    beq t1, x0, strlenend
    addi    t0, t0, 1
    addi    a0, a0, 1
    jal x0, strlenloop
strlenend:
    addi    a0, t0, 0
    jalr    x0, 0(ra)
```

Im guessing my understanding of character pointers and how they are stored on the stack is lacking.

Comment: It is silly to mix `xN` register names with `aN` register names. Just stick with the friendly register names.

Comment: I appreciate the advice but do you know anything about the stack part in trecrev?

Answer (score 1):

Primarily, let's observe that there is no recursion here: this is an iterative algorithm.

```
trecrev:
    bge x0, a1, trecrevbase

    addi sp, sp, -24   # this is written so as to look like function prologue
                       # but it isn't -- it occurs inside the loop
    sd ra, 0(sp)       # silly to save the same, unchanging ra each iteration...
    sd a0, 8(sp)       # saving a0, since the upcoming call will overwrite a0
                       # and we need this variable for the next iteration
    sd a1, 16(sp)      # saving a1, since the upcoming call will overwrite a1
                       # and we need this variable for the next iteration

    add a1, a1, a0     # passing (array, array+index) as a0, a1
    jal ra, excharr

    ld ra, 0(sp)       # this is written so as to look like function epilogue,
                       # but it isn't -- it occurs inside the loop
    ld a0, 8(sp)       #
    ld a1, 16(sp)      #
    addi sp, sp, 24    #

    addi a0, a0, 1
    addi a1, a1, -2

    jal x0, trecrev    # this may look like a call, but it is not.
                       # this is a simple backward branch, 
                       #   effectively forming a loop

trecrevbase:
    jalr x0, 0(ra)
```

The stack is being used as variable storage that will survive the call to `ecxharr`.

The approach is working/workable though arguably flawed because it pushes and pops each iteration, which is both unnecessary and misleading.  Misleading in that it pushes an entire stack frame each iteration, and unnecessarily so.

This can be fixed by moving the stack frame creation outside the loop as in the transformation seen below.

(By definition function prologue occurs before the function body and runs only once; function epilogue occurs after the function body and runs only once.)

```
trecrev:
    addi  sp, sp, -24   # this is function prologue
                        # creating room for saved ra + 2 more slots
    sd ra, 0(sp)        # saving ra (just once!)

loop1:
    bge x0, a1, loop1End

    sd a0, 8(sp)        # saving a0, since the upcoming call will overwrite a0
    sd a1, 16(sp)       # saving a1, since the upcoming call will overwrite a1

    add a1, a1, a0      # passing (array, array+index) as a0, a1
    jal ra, excharr

    ld a0, 8(sp)        # restore the a0 and a1 variables from the stack
    ld a1, 16(sp)

    addi a0, a0, 1
    addi a1, a1, -2

    jal x0, loop1       # loop

loop1End:
    ld ra, 0(sp)        # this is function epilogue
    addi sp, sp, 24     #
    jalr x0, 0(ra)
```

---

Still, the best and most appropriate approach for this scenario is to use `s` registers instead of memory for those variables that need to survive the call to `excharr`.

```
trecrev:
    addi  sp, sp, -24   # this is function prologue
                        # creating room for saved ra + 2 more slots
    sd ra, 0(sp)        # saving ra (just once!)
    sd s0, 8(sp)        # preserving s0 so we can use s0
    sd s1, 16(sp)       # preserving s1 so we can use s1

    move s0, a0         # transfer parameter variables to s regs
    move s1, a1

loop1:
    bge x0, s1, loop1End

    move a0, s0
    add a1, a1, a0      # passing array, array + len as a0, a1
    jal ra, excharr

    addi s0, s0, 1
    addi s1, s1, -2

    jal x0, loop1       # loop

loop1End:
    ld ra, 0(sp)        # this is function epilogue
    ld s0, 8(sp)
    ld s1, 16(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 24
    jalr x0, 0(ra)
```

Using `s` registers instead of stack memory goes from having 2 loads & 2 stores each iteration to having 2 loads and 2 stores only once.

The loop is where the bulk of this function's work takes place, and that loop is now considerably shorter.

(Using `s` regs instead of memory makes the function more expensive only when called with index of 0; when called with an index of 1 it is even, and when called with index > 1 it is a win.)